# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) - Assisted Conversion Paths

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Using the API, is there an equivalent way to pull data from GA4 for assisted conversion paths?

I know that GA4 has this information: Advertising > Attribution > Conversion paths

Similar to how the [Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3) for UA worked.

With MCF API, you would call mcf:assistedConversions and mcf:assistedValue (https://s.vlm.co/E0uRyW01).

So far it appears that I would have to come up with another way to create the same kind of data?

EDIT 1/10/23: I have found this [article](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238770631#comment3), explaining we are limited to "first user source" and "session source" in GA4. I may have to look into the funnel exploration report.

Comment: Were you able to find any way out to add mcf metrics in API ?

Comment: Inspecting the network on the GA4 Conversion paths page, the content for the table calls actually an "Attribution Report" (not a funnel report): https://analytics.google.com/analytics/app/data/v2/venus?dataset=p323390350&gamonitor=gafe&hl=en_US&reportId=explorer_card_0&state=app.reports.reports.attribution

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not in the API. Just as a temporary solution, I made a Google Sheet with an attached Apps Script that you can download and drop your Conversion Path data from GA4 into and it will give you a view of last click, assisted and totals in terms of revenue and sales/events.

Template sheet for seeing assisted conversions in GA4
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vTMcSUcqKPVt5tWldklATZiPqbg7NnPtq_MwlNNxeI/edit#gid=1132797076

There's also a user guide here:
https://coam.io/affiliate-marketing/how-to-see-assisted-conversions-in-ga4